# HTML Canvas: update globalAlpha property

Tags: html, canvas, opacity

I'm trying to update the globalAlpha of a canvas element after its painted. The canvas contains an image, and two texts. I show the code at the bottom.

I want to change the globalAlpha property from 0.6 to 1 afterwards. How can i do this most elegantly with performance in mind?

```
        var ctx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.6;

        //background gradient
        var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, options["height"]);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, options["colorStop0"]);
        gradient.addColorStop(1, options["colorStop1"]);
        ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, options["width"], options["height"]);

        //program
        ctx.font = options.programText["font"];
        ctx.fillStyle = options.programText["color"];
        ctx.fillText(prog.title, options.programText["x"], options.programText["y"]);

        //channel number
        ctx.font = options.channelNumber["font"];
        ctx.fillStyle = options.channelNumber["color"];
        ctx.fillText(item_index + 1, options.channelNumber["x"], options.channelNumber["y"]);

        //channel logo
        var channelLogo = new Image();
        channelLogo.onload = function () {
            var clX = options.channelLogo["x"];
            var clY = options.channelLogo["y"];
            ctx.drawImage(channelLogo, clX, clY, channelLogo.width, channelLogo.height);
        };
        channelLogo.src = this.getChannelLogo(channel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update canvas after painting by just doing pixel manipulation.

Using the getImageData & putImageData method of context of canvas.

But there is not any method like "changeAlpha(x,y,width,height,alphaValue)" of context of canvas.

Same kind of problem i am also facing in my app.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot update the globalAlpha of a shape after it is painted.

More to the point, you cannot "update" *anything* after it is painted. There is no updating in Canvas. You must instead redraw the thing(s) with the attributes changed.

So in your case you will simply want to clear your canvas and redraw everything with globalAlpha set back to 1.

Answer (score 0):

If your alpha is going ***up to 100%***, you can probably just repaint it without redrawing the whole scene (overwriting what was there previously).  The only risk is some antialiasing artifacts if you're doing curves.

If you alpha is going ***down***, however, you have to do as Simon says - repaint the whole scene.

Comment: So how would the code look like when i'd just repaint canvas at going up to 100% alpha? ImageData loop?

Comment: You'd need to redraw the background gradient, program, channel number, channel logo, etc.  Move it into a separate function, and call it twice with two different globalAlphas.  Which is pretty much repainting the whole scene - but if you had other things on the canvas, they wouldn't have to be redrawn.

Comment: but wouldn't for example the new background just be pasted over the old one? the old background wouldn't be cleared, or does it?

Comment: it would just be pasted over, yes.